# String matching not working in bash script

Tags: arrays, regex, linux, bash

This is weird.. mainly because it worked last night. I have a script that is passed in an expression that is supposed to match file names in an array. I'm not allowed to use `find` however (it is for an assignment).

For example if the user passes in the argument `'*.c'`, and I have these files to check it against:

```
~/dir/text1.txt
~/dir/no.c
~/dir/no.sh
```

I do the comparison in a function like so:

```
process ()
{
   local new_cur=()
   for i in "${files[@]}"; do
       if [[ "$i" == "$1" ]]; then
           new_cur+=("$i")
       fi
   done
}
```

I then call this in the bash script like this, where `arguments[1]` is = to `'*.c'`:

`process "${arguments[1]}"`

Inside my `process` function, I checked and the string `*.c` is being passed in, and the files are being passed in. However it is not passing the `if` statement within my function.

Note that this also does not work for even simple strings without wildcards.

Edit: I have also looked up common solutions, and for whatever reason none work. Here is what I have tried:

```
if [ "$i" == "$1" ]
if [ "$1" == "$i" ]
if [ "$i" = "$1" ]
if [ "$1" = "$i" ]
if [[ "$1" = "$i" ]]
if [[ "$i" = "$1" ]]
if [[ "$1" == "$i" ]]
if [[ "$i" == *"$1"* ]]
```

So far none of the above have worked.

Comment: What do you see when you run the script under `set -x` at the beginning?

Comment: @Jens Interesting.. if I have a file called `test.c` it shows that it is checking `[[ test.c == \*\.\c ]]`

Comment: @Jens Changing it to `if [ "$i" == "$1" ]` now shows it testing for `[ test.c = '*.c' ]` and passing in just `*.c` as an argument (no single quotes) shows it as `[ test.c = *.c ]`.. but for whatever reason it still is not showing that it is a match.

Comment: Have you tried [ "$i" =~ "$1" ] ?

Comment: @asimovwasright I'm getting an error that says "`[: =~: binary operator expected`" and doing `if [[ "$i" =~ "$1" ]]` doesn't give me the error but doesn't end up working :(

Comment: '=~' requires double square brackets [[ =~ ]] The regular expression should not be quoted in order to work as such. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: My bad, was getting mixed up in my head... Actually the only thing I can think here is to first declare the glob as a variable, then use the variable in the test. So, declare var="$1" then [ $i ==  $var ] - this might work...

Comment: @asimovwasright Thank you! Although doing `[ $i == $var ]` did not work (and other combinations of this), I found that `[[ "$i" == $var ]]` worked :| Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're welcome! I will place it in the answer, please accept it, so I can get the rep :-)

Comment: Note: If you use double square brackets `[[...]]` in bash you won't need to put quotes around variables. So `[[ $i == $var ]]` always works (in contrast to `[ "$i" == "$var" ]` where quotes are required because otherwise you get errors e.g. if at least one of the variables contain whitespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare the glob as a variable, then use the variable in the test. So, declare:

```
var="$1" then [ $i == $var ]
```

The reason for this is to force bash to expand the wildcard before the test.